# How to use latex standalone package with knitr?

Tags: latex, knitr

I'm trying to generate png pictures of charts using knitr and latex standalone package. The following minimal code compiles but the output is pdf:

```
\documentclass[convert=true]{standalone}
\begin{document}    
    <<test-plot, echo=FALSE>>=
        plot(rnorm(10))
    @
\end{document}
```

Now if I want to pass some options to standalone I must use curly brackets after `convert=`, but simply putting something like `convert={true}` will produce an error:

```
! Argument of \@fileswith@pti@ns has an extra }.
...
```

Something like `convert={true, ghostscript, gsexe=gswin64c, density=1200}` works fine with tikz charts.

Am I overlooking something or maybe a knitr shortcoming? Any ideas on how to go around?

Comment: `convert={true}` can be simplified to `convert` because `true` is the default value for this option

Comment: Yes, `convert`, `convert=true` or `convert={true}` should be the same, but the last one throws an error.